# Adding Custom Airflow Provider to Airflow Running in Docker

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, astronomer

I have Airflow running in Docker. I now want to add my custom airflow provider to it. How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you follow https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers/#how-to-create-your-own-provider guidelines. Otherwise, you do not need any special thing other than installing it in your docker container.

I'll recommend installing it while building the image by adding a command in your docker file to install your custom provider

```
FROM quay.io/astronomer/astro-runtime:8.5.0-base

RUN pip install <PROVIDER_PACKAGE>
```